# Why can't I access array element in string here?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array

```
$array = ['first'=>'hi','second'=>'bye'];
```

Why following syntax is not working

```
 echo " i wanna print $array['first']";
```

The error message is

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING) in

But when I tried

```
 echo "i wanna print $array[first]";
```

did work fine.

So can someone explain what difference single quotes (') making here. And what does above error really mean, any ideas?

Comment: the clean way would by `echo "i wanna print ".$array['first'];`

Comment: dirty way would be `echo "i wanna print {$array[first]}";`

Comment: @apokryfos Why do you consider that way dirty?

Comment: This is the documented way PHP works

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18092288/3933332

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't like how PHP makes a special exception to `$array[index]` when it's within a string. Seems dirty.

Comment: It also was adding comedic value when paired with the first comment

Comment: @apokryfos I thought it may have been for the comedic value when I first saw it

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
echo "i wanna print ".$array['first'];
```

Instead of

```
echo " i wanna print $array['first']";
```

Answer (score -2):

here php will not able to parse the multi dimension array from double quote string, to acheive same functionality you have to enquote the array variable inside {} brackets.

Try below line of code it will work without error.

```
echo " i wanna print {$array['first']}";
```

I hope this help you in understanding.

Comment: RiggsFolly what is wrong with my answer